# Visual Studio 2008 Remote Debugging - Access Denied

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I've had this problem several times before, so please excuse my bluntness. I cannot seem to get VS to debug remotely, nor can I find a rational reason why not. I'm trying very hard to debug the WebServices I'm constructing, and it would be nice if the tools worked.
The given reason **this** time is 'Access is denied.' This is on top of the familiar error message 'Unable to step into remote server' etc. This time, it seems to be accurate; the server runs only from the domain admin account, and if I run Visual Studio as the domain admin, remote debugging is allowed. This is, of course, totally impractical for security.
I have added my user account to the Permissions section, but RD doesn't seem to remember it, even between closing & reopening the monitor with the process running as a service.
I've tried running the debugger as a Service, as a standalone program, without authentication, and manually adding both my user account and my group to the debug list, but no joy. I cannot remember what I did before to get things working, but I do remember having just as much fun.
Everything's the same version - Visual Studio 2008 on my workstation (XP SP3) and the server (Server 2003), using .Net 3.5 for both the client program and the WebServices. If it helps, the server is running IIS 6.0.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, cracked it - Remote Debugging is incapable of remembering that I've added myself to the 'Allowed' list (not that this surprises me at all), so I added myself to the server local Administrators group, which Remote Debugging includes as allowed by default.